# xamarin process start error access denied

Tags: xamarin

i create netcore console application and build to mac-ox self container ..
then i put it to my xamarn.mac project Resource folder.
i write code in xamarin.mac project to run process it.
but error.

[08:51:21]->System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): ApplicationName=‘/Users/yuzd/Projects/AntDeploy/AntDeploy/bin/Debug/AntDeploy.app/Contents/Resources/lib/AntDeployCommand‘, CommandLine=‘/Users/yuzd/.config/AntDeploy/dcf2939703bb226b5390fb310d3a3828.json‘, CurrentDirectory=‘‘, Native error= Access denied
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x0029f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.10.0.157/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System/System.Diagnostics/Process.cs:768 
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x0003a] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.10.0.157/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs:2005 
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at AntDeploy.ViewController.Exec (AntDeploy.Models.Arguments arguments, System.Action`2[T1,T2] log) [0x000b0] in /Users/yuzd/Projects/AntDeploy/AntDeploy/ViewController.cs:1828

i do not want to use 【-R 777】 for my xxx.app folder.
how to access without denied error?

[image]

[image]

XXXX.app folder:

[image]

Comment: Is this a sandboxed entitled app?

Comment: no i have not check sandbox in project setting

Comment: "i do not want to use 【-R 777】 for my xxx.app folder" Why do you need to change permission of the folder, when only change to the executable itself is required?

Comment: i found a solution: use process to excute [ chmod -R 777 ] if err message is  Access denied  . but i am not understand why solved by do this.